# what is a burn in the esophagus called?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

You know how when you drink something freezingly cold you experience a brainfreeze, what about when you eat something extremely hot and you feel the burn in your esophagus. What is that called?

Comment: You could be thinking of *heartburn*

Comment: I sense this is more a medical question, than one about the English language. May I suggest to try google.

Answer (score 1):

In America , I think we would call it

- burning one's throat

I believe that Americans do not commonly/colloquially call it the esophagus; that is more of a medical term.

Note that this is different from

- "having a burning [feeling]" in one's throat

which is usually caused by *acid reflux* (formerly known as *heartburn*), not by heat.